# Error: Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Object', required: 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'

Tags: java, android, rest

I am trying some code on Android for REST client but getting an error at following line:

```
for (NameValuePair p : params) {
}
```

> Error: Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Object', required: 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'

Please note that I also `import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;`

Any help ?

Comment: 'params' is not an interable of 'NamedValuePair'. Instead it "contains" 'Object'.

Comment: Can you tell params is object of which class is it ArrayList or Json object or what????

Comment: your **params** is not iterrable of NameValuePair, but it has to be to be able to be used in your for()

Comment: params is an object of type ArrayList

Comment: Please post the definition of your `params` variable to the question (not as a comment).

Comment: Are you targeting API 23? (M Preview). If so, the apache HTTP client and classes have been removed in favor of UrlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

For following line to be working

```
for(NameValuePair p : params) { }
```

`params` type should be Array or List or collection of `NameValuePair` objects.

Comment: params is an object of ArrayList

Comment: But you must have kept objects of `Object` in the arraylist and not the objects of `NameValuePair`

Comment: couldn't understand what i am doing wrong.. i am a beginner.

Comment: Can you paste your code for `params` ? How are you keeping data in it